# How does (wikipedia's axiomatization of) intuitionistic logic prove $p \rightarrow p$?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

I'm looking at [Wikipedia's article on Intuitionist logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus), and I can't figure out how it would prove $(p \rightarrow p)$.

Does it prove $(p \rightarrow p)$?  If yes, how?

If no, is there a correct (or reasonable, if there is no "correct") axiomatization of intuitionistic logic available anywhere online?

Comment: As you can see from the answer below, the "standard" derivation, in an *Hilbert-style* proof system, of $p \rightarrow p$ use only the propositional axioms THEN-1 and THEN-2. They are both intuitionistically available. In classical logic, where $p \rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$, the *tautology* $p \rightarrow p$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor p$, i.e. to *Excluded Middle*; this does not work in *intuitionistic logic*, where the connectives are not interdefinable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. $p→(p→p)$ (THEN-1)
2. $p→((p→p)→p)$ (THEN-1)
3. $(p→((p→p)→p))→((p→(p→p))→(p→p))$ (THEN-2)
4. $(p→(p→p))→(p→p)$ (MP from lines 2,3)
5. $(p→p)$ (MP from lines 1,4)

Comment: Note that in the simply-typed lambda calculus, this corresponds to the identity $I = SKK$.